# Как хранить List в cookies или в session в течении длительного времени и при перезагрузки браузера

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, cookie, сессия

Хочу хранить List в cookies или в session, но столкнулся с проблемой, session удаляет List при перезапуске браузера, а cookies, как я понял, может хранить только строку.  Как лучше реализовать, чтоб хранить List хотя бы час-два, не используя БД.

Comment: можно сериализовать список и хранить его в куках... только наверное не нужно слишком много туда данных класть
ибо вы их гоняете туда-сюда при каждом запросе

Comment: Есть вариант с localStorage. Но он тоже хранит строки которые нужно сериализовать туда и обратно